# WordPress refuses to read the .htaccess file and gives a 404 for sub-pages

Tags: 404-error, apache

I have a DigitalOcean server with Apache2 installed, which runs virtual hosts.

I have set up the site in a sub-folder `var/www/html/[site-name]`. The URL being something like `192.168.1.8/[site-name]/`.

All was working well until I created a virtual hosts `.conf` file and pointed a domain to the server.

The home page loads, but non of the subpages. If reset the permalinks to default, they load fine like `192.168.1.8?p=123`.

Normally the problem would either be `AllowOverride All` not set, `a2enmod rewrite` not on, or the `.htaccess` file is not there or doesn't have the correct permissions.

I've never seen this problem before! Do you know what may be up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the `000-default.conf` file had...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I had to place...

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Into the `apache2.conf`

And use the `sudo service apache2 restart` command.